# Trying to work with openlayers, Golden Layout, reactjs. But openlayers map only show in 1 window of golden-layout not in other

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, golden-layout

Trying to work with openlayers,reactjs and golden-layout.
Golden-layout configuration is one row with two "react-components" inside it.
Openlayers does render map in one "react-component" of golden-layout but not in other "react-component".

Here is code i am trying.

```
    import Map from 'ol/Map';

    import View from 'ol/View';
    import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
    import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    // import TestComponent from './App';
    import GoldenLayout from "golden-layout";
    import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
    import "golden-layout/src/css/goldenlayout-base.css";
    import "golden-layout/src/css/goldenlayout-dark-theme.css";
    import "ol/ol.css";
    window.React = React;
    window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;

    var map = new Map({
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
          })
        })
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
      })
    });


    class TestComponent extends React.Component{
      componentDidMount() {
        map.setTarget("map")
      }
        render() {
            return (<div id="map"></div>)
        }
    }

    var myLayout = new GoldenLayout({
        content: [
          {
            type: 'row',
            content:[
              {
                type:'react-component',
                component: 'test-component',
              },
              {
                type:'react-component',
                component: 'test-component',
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    });


    myLayout.registerComponent( 'test-component', TestComponent);

    myLayout.init();
```

Here is result.
[openlayers with reactjs and golden-layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhHyM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need two instances of openlayers map and also element with unique `id`.

if only one instance of map used, then changing it's target element will not render map in both elements.

So need two instances of map, with unique element `id`.

Also golden-layout renders the provided react component in it's layout/reat-component which means you need to set the `id` in `componentDidMount()` function of reactjs component life cycle.
[componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Here is code that work.

```
    import Map1 from 'ol/Map';
    import Map2 from 'ol/Map';
    import View from 'ol/View';
    import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
    import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    // import TestComponent from './App';
    import GoldenLayout from "golden-layout";
    import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
    import "golden-layout/src/css/goldenlayout-base.css";
    import "golden-layout/src/css/goldenlayout-dark-theme.css";
    import "ol/ol.css";
    window.React = React;
    window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;

    var map1 = new Map1({
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
          })
        })
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
      })
    });

    var map2 = new Map2({
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
          })
        })
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
      })
    });


    class TestComponent extends React.Component{
      constructor(){
        super()
        this.myref = React.createRef()
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.myref.current.setAttribute("id",this.props.id)
        this.props.map.setTarget(this.props.id)
      }
      render() {
          return (
            <div ref={this.myref}></div>
          )
      }
    }

    var myLayout = new GoldenLayout({
        content: [
          {
            type: 'row',
            content:[
              {
                type:'react-component',
                component: 'test-component',
                props:{id:"map1",map:map1}
              },
              {
                type:'react-component',
                component: 'test-component',
                props:{id:"map2",map:map2}
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    });


    myLayout.registerComponent( 'test-component', TestComponent);

    myLayout.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the id of the second map.

First of all, the value of `id` attribute should be **unique** across the whole app (well, at least unique in the output that you are currently showing to the user). Both of your maps are pointing at the same div element with `id="map"` (probably the first that they find).

So your first map can potentially target div with `id="map1"` and the second map component should target div with `id="map2"`.

So you should try to put the map `id` as a prop to both of your components and set the *target id* and *div id* in `render()` method based on this property

Please, let me know if my answer helped you!

Comment: yah it really help me to set `id` of current div with help of React refs [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref).

but now this time it will set map in second window with `id` "map2" and map disappear in first window with `id` "map1".which means that current instance of map changes its rendering div. i need to import another instance of map.
and it work


But thanks it really help me

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!